# Action Button are not displaying at the top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a menu.xml file with three button..but the buttons are not comming at the top of the actionbar.They are comming at the bottom
Any body has any idea for that..I m sharing my main.xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_contact"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_task"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/add_task"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/gray"
                android:title="@string/gray"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/green"
                android:title="@string/green"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/red"
                android:title="@string/red"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/orange"
                android:title="@string/orange"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/blue"
                android:title="@string/blue"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/purple"
                android:title="@string/dark_blue"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

In the mainActivity I have override the option menu as:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Activity in manifest. If you set android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" parameter, remove this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this to your code:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```